# How to get file handler for reading real time input stream in perl script by ignoring the command line arguments

Tags: perl, stdin

I have a perl script that accepts a command line arguments (file name) and it should read the input stream to write into the file created using the argument.

The problem is that the statement while (<>), instead of waiting for the user input to write into the file , tries to open the file.
I cannot use `<STDIN>` because I need to call this script from my Java program

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw ( fatalsToBrowser );
use warnings;

#store the input parameter File_Name
my $cfgFileName;
my $q = CGI->new(); 
$cfgFileName = $q->param('fileName');

#Open the file and write input data
open (OUT, "> /home/$cfgFileName") or die $!;

print "content-type: text/plain\n\n";
while ( <>) 
{
   print OUT $_;
}
close (OUT); 

# pass the status
print "SUCCESS";

exit 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're labouring under a misconception. The input stream *for this program* is `STDIN`. It's not a global thing.

The "diamond operator" `<>` works like this:

- if filenames are specified as arguments, it opens them and 'streams' them through `STDIN`.
- if no filenames are specified, it reads `STDIN`.

If you don't want the former to apply, then you want to read `STDIN`. It doesn't matter where you call the program from - `STDIN`, `STDOUT` and `STDERR` are program specific what 'pipe' `|` does is link one program's `STDOUT` to the next program's `STDIN`.

Most `exec` or `system` calls will do the same thing.

You should also avoid calling `open` like that - it's bad style. Try instead:

```
open ( my $output, ">", "/home/$cfgFileName" ) or die $!;
```

and then:

```
print {$output} $_
```

By doing it this way:

- you lexically scope your filehandles, so you're not polluting your namespace, and allow the program to detect and close when they go out of scope.
- You avoid interpolation issues of variable names entirely (e.g. unwanted "pipe" "truncate" etc.).

Comment: Thanks Sobrique. But my problem is still unsolved. If I use while(<STDIN>) my code works fine from the console, but if fails if i call it from my Java Program. 
I pass the data to be written in the file from Java over URL Connection. 
It throws this exception when I try to read the response : Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL:......

Comment: Ah, so you're `POST`ing to a web server? That's still `STDIN`. `500` error means "something went wrong before script headers were printed". Check your error logs on your httpd. Alternatively - move your `print content-type` line further up your script so it happens earlier.

Comment: By moving the 'print content-type' line further up, I am no more getting the 500 Error code. But I am still facing a weird problem. If I run the script directly from the browser an Empty file gets created. But if I fire it from the Java code the 'open' statement fails. It says that "/home/$cfgFileName" is a directory . My argument is "fileName=ueCfgFile.csv". :(

Comment: Probably means `$cfgFileName` is null, and so it's trying to hit `/home`. Try printing it :). Bear in mind that the CGI `param` method reads from an environment variable `$ENV{'QUERY_STRING'}` set by the httpd. Passing it on the command line won't work.